# Spring Rest Repository Error

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

In a Rest Spring API in Repositories, I need to find values by three parameters but that is the phone, password, finds delete=0 finding by. I have already added It to the entity but it is showing error invalid derived query! No property is-deleted found for type CustomerEntity! two field is working fine but is-deleted is not working

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerEntity, Long> {
CustomerEntity findByfacebookID(String facebookID);
CustomerEntity findByPhoneAndPasswordAndIsDeleted(String phone, String password, Boolean isdeleted);
```

entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class CustomerEntity {

    @Column(name = "IS_DELETED", length = 3, nullable = false)
    private Boolean isdeleted;
```

Comment: why you do have a space in property name? exactly in `private Boolean is deleted`

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA assumes that your field names follow certain conventions in order to correctly generate derived queries. Capitalization matters; `isdeleted != isDeleted`. In addition, `IsXYZ` has a [special meaning](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_query_keywords) in Spring Data JPA queries, and is likely to cause ambiguities in your syntax. In general, stick to conventions and things will be much simpler:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerEntity, Long> {
    CustomerEntity findByfacebookID(String facebookID);

    CustomerEntity findByPhoneAndPasswordAndDeleted(String phone, String password, Boolean deleted);
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class CustomerEntity {

    @Column(name = "IS_DELETED", length = 3, nullable = false)
    private Boolean deleted;

    // phone, password, other fields...
}
```

In short: remove the `is` prefix from your boolean variable (that is typically used in the method name of the accessor, rather than in the field name).

Comment: Worth noting: based on the error message you're seeing, simply capitalizing the `d` in `private Boolean isdeleted;` would also likely fix this issue, but it's worth making the full update to avoid ambiguity in your query for the next change.

Comment: thanks nbrooks its working is yes it was the problem of d .i have to use it in small caps Isdeleted